# Using wordpress as landing page that works with silverlight back end

Tags: php, asp.net, html, silverlight, wordpress

I am web developer working on a wordpress landing page that will lead the user into an all silverlight page. Now my programmer says this can't be done and it's not supported php conflicts with silverlight/asp and so on.

My web address will be www.maddog.net... I need the wordpress and silverlight portions of the website to reside in the same URL.

One more note I had a a login developed for the wordpress site that will need to talk to the silverlight logon... is this possible?

Comment: Why are you using Wordpress as a landing page? It's a full-blown web application/CMS/blog, not just a single page...

Answer (score 0):

Just have your PHP (wordpress) redirect to a .NET based subdomain application if need be.  The silverlight elements need to be hosted by asp.net based pages so for example:

You should be able to set this up in IIS, PHP root level site and /Subsite as its own virtual directory hosting asp.net site.

User logs into php page, you can server transfer to next page with login details etc or any other way to want to pass the creds to the .NET page and automatically log the user in then display the silverlight component.